# Call function from Stateful Widget from another StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I have a `ProfilePage` which is a `StatelessWidget` and inside of it's build method I display a form called `MyForm` which is a `StatefulWidget` and a widget called `FancyFab` which is another `StatefulWidget`.

Here's an example of how they are displayed on the parent widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext globalContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Profile')),
      floatingActionButton: FancyFab(),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: initData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return MyForm(data: snapshot.data);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error);
              return new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        )
      )
  );
}
```

My problem lies in that I have a `saveData()` function in `MyFormState` which grabs values from each `TextFormField` controller and saves it on the database. I need to call this function from within my `FancyFab` widget but I can't find a proper way to do so. Or even access those `TextFormField` controllers from within my `FancyFab` widget. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here's how I implemented the `FancyFab` widget:

```
class FancyFab extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tooltip;
  final IconData icon;
  String photo;
  TextEditingController birthController;
  TextEditingController firstController;
  TextEditingController lastController;
  TextEditingController emailController;
  TextEditingController phoneController;
  TextEditingController associationController;
  TextEditingController countryController;

  final Function saveData;

  FancyFab({ 
  this.tooltip, 
  this.icon, 
  this.saveData,
  this.firstController,
  this.lastController,
  this.emailController,
  this.phoneController,
  this.associationController,
  this.countryController,
  this.birthController,
  this.photo});

  @override
  _FancyFabState createState() => _FancyFabState();
}

class _FancyFabState extends State<FancyFab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isOpened = false;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Color> _buttonColor;
  Animation<double> _animateIcon;
  Animation<double> _translateButton;
  Curve _curve = Curves.easeOut;
  double _fabHeight = 56.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
    _animateIcon =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    _buttonColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.pink,
      end: Colors.red,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.00,
        1.00,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ));
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: _fabHeight,
      end: -14.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  animate() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  }

  Widget save() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'saveBtn',
        onPressed: () {

        },
        tooltip: 'Save',
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget image() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: 'imageBtn',
        onPressed: () async {
          File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.IMAGE); 

                  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Uploading photo'),
                            titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            elevation:10,
                            content: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );

                  final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(file.path);

                  final String fileName = file.path;

                  final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
                    File(fileName),
                  ); 

                  final StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = 
                  (await uploadTask.onComplete);
                  final String url = (await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
                  print('URL Is $url');
                  setState(() {
                    widget.photo = url;
                  });
        },
        tooltip: 'Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.image),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget toggle() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor.value,
        onPressed: animate,
        heroTag: 'toggleBtn',
        tooltip: 'Toggle',
        child: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _animateIcon,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 2.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: save(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 1.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: image(),
        ),
        toggle(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can read more about that : https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: Can you give more information on how you have implemented the FancyFab?

Comment: @thusith.92 updated the question with your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by nesting a `Scaffold` inside `MyForm` widget. Then the tree changed and my `FancyFab` widget was now a child from `MyForm` widget. Next I passed parent's `saveData()` function and all my controllers to my child widget and that way I was able to call parent function providing the appropiate data. The fix was a follows:

## Solution

### Parent widget (MyForm)

```
class MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {

  User user;
  TextEditingController birthController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController firstController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController associationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController countryController = TextEditingController();



    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = widget.data[1];
    firstController.text = user.firstName;
    lastController.text = user.lastName;
    countryController.text = user.country;
    birthController.text = user.dateBirth;
    emailController.text = user.email;
    phoneController.text = user.phone;
    associationController.text = user.association;
  }

 _updatePhoto(String text) {
    setState(() {
      user.photo = text;
    });
  }

  _saveData(data, BuildContext ctx) async {
    FirebaseUser fireUser= await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    var uid = fireUser.uid;
    await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).updateData(data).then((val) {
     AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Confirmation'),
                            titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            elevation:10,
                            content: Text('Your profile has been saved.')

    );

    showDialog(context: ctx,
                    builder: (BuildContext context){
                      return alert;
    });

    })
    .catchError((err) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('There have been an error updating your profile' + err.toString()),
      elevation: 10,
    );
    Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    });

  }



    @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FancyFab(
              parentAction: _updatePhoto,
              saveData: _saveData,
              firstController: firstController,
              lastController: lastController,
              emailController: emailController,
              countryController: countryController,
              associationController: associationController,
              phoneController: phoneController,
              birthController: birthController,
              photo: user.photo),
            body:Form(
               //more UI
            )
           );
   }
}
```

### Child widget (FancyFab)

```
class FancyFab extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function(String value) parentAction;
  final void Function(dynamic data, BuildContext ctx) saveData;
  final String tooltip;
  final IconData icon;
  String photo;
  TextEditingController birthController;
  TextEditingController firstController;
  TextEditingController lastController;
  TextEditingController emailController;
  TextEditingController phoneController;
  TextEditingController associationController;
  TextEditingController countryController;


  FancyFab({ 
  this.parentAction,
  this.tooltip, 
  this.icon, 
  this.saveData,
  this.firstController,
  this.lastController,
  this.emailController,
  this.phoneController,
  this.associationController,
  this.countryController,
  this.birthController,
  this.photo});

  @override
  _FancyFabState createState() => _FancyFabState();
}
```

Then I could just call parent function using `widget.parentFunction(data)` on my child widget state.

Special thanks to **@diegoveloper** for providing with a great article explaining the types of widgets interactions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is a slight issue with the data-flow of the application, for example, strictly from a fucntionality based observation, the data and the trigger (FancyFab) should be in the same widget or in an directly accessible widget. But nevertheless if you want to continue, [here](https://github.com/ThuAbLKA/fancy_fab) is a very primitive (VERY) way to do it.